# How to add a spinner to a splashscreen in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, spinner, splash-screen

I have implemented a Splash Screen on an android app I am building using Android Studio and I would like to add a spinner to the splash screen. Can anyone give me a hand on this:

Here is the code on my splashScreen.java Class:

```
package com.packagename.appname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * Created by VAIO1 on 05/09/2014.
 */
public class splashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                    try {
                           sleep(3000);
                           Intent splashIntent = new Intent("com.packagename.appname.SPLASH");
                           startActivity(splashIntent);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                            finish();
                    }
               }

        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/splashId">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/screen"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for any feedback on how to achieve this.

Comment: what use of spinner in splashActivity?

Comment: Why are you so intent on wasting three seconds of your users' time each time they start your app? It's silly, unnecessary, and will get you uninstalled in no time. Use splash screens *only* if you're actually doing something -- like loading data or preparing assets.

Comment: it is a private app which is used internally in my company... so it is not waste of time. so your comment has absolutely not effect on my decision of using a splashscreen that lasts 2 or 3 seconds, period..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use this code :-


public class splashScreen extends Activity {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                    try {
                           sleep(3000);

                            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Sync_Screen_activity.this);
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Wait..");

                            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                            progressDialog.show();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                           Intent splashIntent = new Intent("com.packagename.appname.SPLASH");
                           startActivity(splashIntent);
                            finish();
                    }
               }

        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi DaxeshKhatri Thanks for your answer... Should I put my SplashScreen activity name in (Sync_Screen_activity.this) ?

Comment: I added the code and and specified progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(splashScreen.this); and it´s not showing the spinner... I set import android.app.ProgressDialog; obviously when I added the code....

Comment: Thank you for your help... I made it work but the four lines of code corresponding progressDialog go under setContentView(R.layout.splash);